# Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__ while running the lookup plugin 'hashi_vault'

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, hashicorp-vault

I'm using hashi_vault to retrieve secrets from HashiCorp’s vault in ansible playbook.

```
 - name: Return all secrets from a path
set_fact:
   vault_result: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/key:value token=token url=https://vaultaddress/ui/vault/secrets/secret/list/folder/subfolder/environment/')}}"

tags:
   - vault
```

command i'm using to run pl is ansible-playbook -v plybook.yml --tags vault

I'm getting following error:

> fatal: [server_addr]: FAILED! => {
>       "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'hashi_vault'. Error was a ,
>   original message: 'Response' object has no attribute '**getitem**'" }

- My python version is Python 2.7.5
- My pip versin is pip 20.1

Comment: It probably means that is not a valid path to a secret.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have changed the script as follows, still the same issue               - name: Return all secrets from a path
    set_fact:
       vault_result: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/key:value token=token url=https://vaultaddress/ui/vault/secrets/secret/list/folder/subfolder/environment/')}}"

    tags:
       - vault